# Is there a good calendar service that doesn't forget appointments like Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I've been using Google Calendar for years now to remind me of appointments. I set it to send me an email before an appointment, and I rely on that email to remember the appointment. I like the fact that I can put something in my calendar and then completely forget about it, trusting that the calendar will remind me of it in the time that I've set.

But for the last few months I've noticed that Google Calendar sometimes simply forgets appointments. It happened many times, both for recurring events and non-recurring events, and with different alert options. (Email, SMS and pop-up.) Over the last two days it forgot about 5 reminders, and now I'm really pissed and I want to find another calendar service. Google Calendar's UI is excellent, but the fact that it forgets reminders is simply unforgivable. I have also contacted them about it and was ignored.

Can anyone recommend a good quality calendar service that I can count on? I'd also consider paying for one.

Comment: I have never had the problems with Google Calendar that you have described, but instead of looking for another service, have you tried to diagnose the problem - Is your email getting filtered or arriving late? Are you sure you have reminders set up on your appointments? Are you sure you checked the box to receive an email? If you have checked these things, have you contacted Google for support? It just seems a lot easier to try to get help than to migrate to an entirely new service.

Comment: The mail isn't arriving at all, not in spam or any other label either. Yes, I'm sure I actually set an email alert. Yes, I have contacted Google for support and was ignored.

Comment: I've had these problems before too and they were never resolved.

Comment: The Google app for iPhone now does PUSH notifications for Calendar + Mail.

Comment: Thanks for info Andrew. Unfortunately I don't own an iPhone.

Comment: @Andrew Lewis - is there a similar app for the Android series? Mail shows up [almost] instantly on my wife's Android phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to get Google Calendar to sync to Thunderbird/iCal on a Desktop or iPhone/iPod touch/Android device and have that device do the reminding. You will know for certain that the offline calendar will work if your events are synching to that device's calendar.

[Here](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/ways-to-send-future-email-gmail-outlook-tools/) are a number of "send future email" options:

1. Use Gmail to Send future email
2. In.com web based Future Email
3. Use Delay email feature in Outlook
4. Thunderbird ‘Send It Later’ plugin
5. <strike>Use Google Calendar for future email</strike> <-- this is your problem
6. Online tools, apps for Future Email

See the link for details.

Answer (score 2):

I use Google Calendar in conjunction with Thunderbird (which is open all the time when I'm at work). I set up events in Google, but Thunderbird does the reminding.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [RememberTheMilk](http://rememberthemilk.com/) and it has been working fine for me.  There are two account types, free (what I use) & pro.  They have a number of apps (for iPhone etc) as well as supporting setting up tasks by email.

Another one I have seen is [HiTask](http://hitask.com).  I haven't used it as much, but it comes in 3 levels, free, premium & business.

Comment: I've been trying to import my Google Calendar into either RememberTheMil and HiTask, but haven't been successful... Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Perhaps another question for WebApps?  There is the RTM help items "http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/about/googlecalendar.rtm" & "http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/troubleshooting/googlecalendar.rtm", but they seem to be talking about going the other way.

Comment: HiTask has introduced synchronization with Google Calendar and Facebook recently. See http://blog.hitask.com/post/69888537615/introducing-google-calendar-sync.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some free services that have the features you seem to be looking for (repeating, reminders via email and other means).

**Portals** - 
IMO you can be sure they will be around for a long while, they are free and have mobile options

calendar.yahoo.com

calendar.live.com

**Dedicated Services** - 
Focused on calendars with nifty features and interfaces.  Startups though, so who knows how long they will be around.

30boxes.com/welcome.php

iscrybe.com/ (Currently in closed beta)

**Professional Service** - 
This is the only one that I have used on the professional side for complex scheduling.  The personal version used to be free, but now had a 30 day trial and is $29.95/yr.  Profitable company. Will synch with gmail.

www.timetrade.com/product.aspx